# Best practice to simulate exception for no space left on disk in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, testing, exception

I am currently writing a wrapper class for OpenCVs implementation of capturing images with a webcam. 
I want to catch the error exception when the space on disk is full. The code for it would look like the following:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_idx)
ret, frame = cap.retrieve()


try:
 cv2.imwrite('test.png',frame)
except IOError:
 print("ERROR ON WRITING")
```

While this will catch the exception, I was wondering if this will also catch other Exceptions and how to only catch the exception for disk full, and what would be the best practice for making a test for this code snippet (besides filling up my disk with so much stuff that the hard drive is really full)

Comment: This question (or at least the answer) is of course platform-dependent, but might I suggest that you plug in a USB drive with stuff on that you don't much care about, and fill that up, and see what IOError reports. You will naturally need to do something like `except IOError as e: print (str(e))` to find this out.

Answer (score 3):

Use [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/exceptions.html#OSError) and check a result for [errno.ENOSPC](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/errno.html#errno.ENOSPC):

```
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.ENOSPC:
```

To check free disk space you can use:

```
psutil.disk_usage(path).free
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, this will only show how to catch the error but not how to simulate this error for test purposes